# Why should I type the full name with extension in start menu?

Tags: windows, windows-search

In Windows' start menu when I type `services` it doesn't show any results, but when I type `services.msc` it shows results.

What is the reason?

For `regedit.exe` I can leave the suffix off. Why does `services.msc` need the suffix? Why is the suffix `.msc` necessary when `.com` and `.exe` can be left off of commands?

Comment: Is this a general learning question or are you actually looking for a solution to this problem? Also have you done any research which might lead you to an answer?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams This is a general question. I just wanted to know the reason.

Comment: General questions are off topic. We need people to ask real-world questions about real-world issues they are having

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a left-over convention from the old *DOS* days.

When you typed the name of a program, *DOS* automatically checked if there was a file named

{what you typed in} + .bat / .exe / .com

If there is no file of that name with with either .exe .bat or .com extension then your command failed, because there was no 'program' by that name.

nowadays in MS Windows you can type the full name of other files such as *myfile.xls*, and windows will fire up the corresponding application that can deal with the file.

.msc is one of those types of file, it needs a program to interpret and 'run' the file. I think it fires up *mmc.exe*

Comment: If I type services into my search bar I get the correct result. Which OS's would your answer be relevant to?

Comment: the start menu is usually a place for executable programs, since services is not executable by itself, it won't show up in the start menu?

Comment: | Yes this is generally true, but the OP is discussing services not showing up in a start menu search without the extension, which I can do perfectly fine without the extension indicating your answer is incorrect. Might you be able to explain this discrepancy? Thanks.

Comment: This is probably due to a setting you can find in File explorer under `Organise/Folder and Search Options / Search / Find Partial Matches`. Program files will be a full match even without the extension whereas other types of files will need to be typed in with an extension

Comment: Thanks for the information and clarification. Rather interesting.